# swift fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value with Any Array

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, option-type, swift3

I realize there have been several 'similar' errors posted about this, but they don't seem to be helping me in my case. It's also possible the syntax isn't working how I'm expecting it to work in Swift:

There are no compile errors, or warnings, just a runtime error

```
var allPlayerSpawnState: Array<Array<Any>>!

var pName: String = "defaultPlayerName"
var pShape = "box"
var pDimensions = SCNVector4(1,1,1,0) 
var pPosition = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
var pRotation = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
var pForce = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
var pTorque = SCNVector4(0, 0, 0, 0)
var pSkinArray = [UIColor]()
var pEmitter = false
var pEmitterUIColor = UIColor.random() // custom random color
var pState: SCNPhysicsBodyType = .Static 

... values change here

print("\n\(pName)")
print(pShape)
print(pDimensions)
print(pPosition)
print(pRotation)
print(pForce)
print(pTorque)
print(pSkinArray)
print(pEmitter)
print(pEmitterUIColor)
print("\(pState)\n")

let tempArray: Array<Any> = [pName, pShape, pDimensions, pPosition, pRotation, pForce, pTorque, pSkinArray, pEmitter, pEmitterUIColor, pState]
allPlayerSpawnState.append(tempArray) // runtime error here: "Thread 1: EXE_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXE_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

... later wanting to use it like this:

for i in allPlayerSpawnState {
    some_function(i[0] as! String, pShape: i[1] as! String, pDimensions: i[2] as! SCNVector4, pPosition: i[3] as! SCNVector3, pRotation: i[4] as! SCNVector3, pForce: i[5] as! SCNVector3, pTorque: i[6] as! SCNVector4, pSkinArray: i[7] as! [UIColor], pEmitter: i[8] as! Bool, pEmitterUIColor: i[9] as! UIColor, pState: i[10] as! SCNPhysicsBodyType)
}
```

and here is the output

```
nameOfPlayer
sphere
SCNVector4(x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0, w: 0.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: -10.0, z: 0.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0)
[UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 1 1]
true
UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1
SCNPhysicsBodyType

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

when I option-click the elements in the array, none of them are optional, so I don't know what the error is trying to indicate.

Any help is appreciated. If you know of a way I can do it without using "Any" that might help me prevent a future potential problem indicated after "... later wanting to do it like this:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is declared but not initialized. At the moment you are going to append something to the array it's `nil` and causes a runtime error.

Initialize the array this way:

```
var allPlayerSpawnState = Array<Array<Any>>()
```

Comment: You know when you spend 4 hours looking at something and then it takes somebody else 2 seconds to figure it out? I'm having one of those moments. Much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Try to use non-optional types as much as possible. It dramatically reduces those errors.